# How to transfer funds from smart contract to account OTHER than msg.sender?

Tags: solidity, transfer, smartcontracts, truffle

I am trying to transfer part of funds stored in a smart contract to an account other than the one calling the function (msg.sender). My function is pretty much like this:

```
function getFunds(address addr, uint amount) public {
    require (address.this(balance)>= amount);
    addr.transfer(amount);
}
```

What I get when I compile in Truffle is:

> Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.

As if it is looking for members in a struct.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @ferit I d appreciate your help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since solidity 0.5 addresses should be `payable` in order to transfer eth to them

```
function getFunds(address payable addr, uint amount) public {
    require (address.this(balance)>= amount);
    addr.transfer(amount);
}
```

For mapping of a struct you can use like this

```
contract testContract {

    mapping(uint256 => test) testAddressMapping; 
    struct test {
        address payable testAddress;
    }

    function testFunction() external{
        testAddressMapping[0].testAddress.transfer(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the address I wanna use is stored in a mapping instead of passed as an argument, how would I make that work?

Comment: you can just add payable mapping(uint256 => address payable) mappingOfAddresses;

Comment: address payable is just a type of address

Comment: Its actually a mapping to a struct, the address being in the struct. Adding payable to the address in the struct constructor did not work...

Comment: it should work. mapping(uint256 => test) testAddressMapping; struct test {address payable testAddress;} Can you show how do you use it?

Comment: Exactly like this. mapping(bytes32=>Org) all_orgs; struct Org { bytes32 name; address payable addr; bytes32 key;}

Comment: Still the same one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200022/discussion-between-vitaly-migunov-and-iraspberrypi).